# Issue passing data to iOS UIViewController

Tags: swift, casting, uiviewcontroller

Im trying to pass an enum to a `UIViewController` in another storyboard but the error is that `UIViewController` has no member `ViewType`. When I checked the variable type after forcing `!`  it is still a `UIViewController` not a `QuotesTestmoniesViewController`

How come the type of the variable is not being changed to the new view controller type? What am I doing wrong here?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    var viewController = UIViewController()
    
    switch indexPath.item {
    //Saints
    case 0:
        viewController = self.amiStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "militarysaintscontroller") as! SaintsViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    //Prayers
    case 1:
        break;
    //Testmonies
    case 2:
        break;
    //Quotes
    case 3:
        viewController = self.amiStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "militaryquotestestmoniescontroller") as! QuotesTestmoniesViewController
        viewController.viewType = ViewType.Quotes //ERROR
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this : ```(viewController as? QuotesTestmoniesViewController).viewType = ViewType.Quotes```

Comment: Yes seems like it is working. But why didn't the type change first time? Is this a bug or something?

Comment: You don't have to write your code messy like that cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use a single line for pushing the different view controller.

But in code your are also written push line for all cases.

It will not work by casting the value and assign. You have to cast the controller at the time of passing data. Like this

```
(viewController as? QuotesTestmoniesViewController).viewType = ViewType.Quotes
```

You can make a generic function for pushing view controller like this

```
func pushNextViewController<T: UIViewController>(viewController: T) {
   self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Usage :

```
let viewController = self.amiStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "militaryquotestestmoniescontroller") as! QuotesTestmoniesViewController
      viewController.viewType = ViewType.Quotes
pushNextViewController(viewController: viewController)

//----

let viewController2 = self.amiStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "militarysaintscontroller") as! SaintsViewController
pushNextViewController(viewController: viewController2)
```

Comment: I liked the generic function usage here. I called the function after the switch statement once.

Answer (score 0):

A variable of type T can hold values of type T. Doesn’t matter if you do something like assign it using an expression in which you cast a T to a U. Still a variable of type T.